# How change threads with processes?

Tags: c, multithreading, fork, multiple-processes

How to rewrite this code using processes instead of threads?How can I replace threads with processes, in this file without starting other files manually?Code is not complete but header files are not necessary here.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t p1_p2;
sem_t p2_p3p5;
sem_t p3_p4;
sem_t p4p5_p6;

void* P1(void *args)
{
    OS_WORK();
    OS_SEM_UP(p1_p2);
}
 
void* P2(void *args)
{
    OS_SEM_DOWN(p1_p2);
    OS_WORK();
    OS_SEM_UP(p2_p3p5);
    OS_SEM_UP(p2_p3p5);
}

void* P3(void *args)
{
    OS_SEM_DOWN(p2_p3p5);
    OS_CS_WORK();
    OS_SEM_UP(p3_p4);
}

void* P4(void *args)
{
    OS_SEM_DOWN(p3_p4);
    OS_CS_WORK();
    OS_SEM_UP(p4p5_p6);
}

void* P5(void *args)
{
    OS_SEM_DOWN(p2_p3p5);
    OS_CS_WORK();
    OS_SEM_UP(p4p5_p6);
}

void* P6(void *args)
{
    OS_SEM_DOWN(p4p5_p6);
    OS_SEM_DOWN(p4p5_p6);
    OS_WORK();
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{
    pthread_t p1, p2, p3, p4, p5, p6;

    os_base_init(TRUE, TRUE);

    OS_SEM_INIT(p1_p2, 0);
    OS_SEM_INIT(p2_p3p5, 0);
    OS_SEM_INIT(p3_p4, 0);
    OS_SEM_INIT(p4p5_p6, 0);

    pthread_create(&p6, NULL, P6, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p5, NULL, P5, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p4, NULL, P4, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p3, NULL, P3, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p2, NULL, P2, NULL);
    pthread_create(&p1, NULL, P1, NULL);

    pthread_join(p1, NULL);
    pthread_join(p2, NULL);
    pthread_join(p3, NULL);
    pthread_join(p4, NULL);
    pthread_join(p5, NULL);
    pthread_join(p6, NULL);

    OS_SEM_DESTROY(p1_p2);
    OS_SEM_DESTROY(p2_p3p5);
    OS_SEM_DESTROY(p3_p4);
    OS_SEM_DESTROY(p4p5_p6);

    os_base_destroy();

    return 0;
}
```

How to rewrite this code using processes instead of threads?How can I replace threads with processes, in this file without starting other files manually?Code is not complete but header files are not necessary here.

Comment: Two questions: 1) Why do you want to switch/what benefit do you expect to derive from separate processes? (multiprocess designs are less portable, and generally more expensive, memory-wise, so the benefits had better be pretty significant) 2) Are you on a system that [provides `fork`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (most OSes save Windows), and is there any reason not to use it (some of the higher level macOS system libraries are not `fork`-safe, so even though it exists, it's dangerous)?

Comment: @ShadowRanger 2) Yes I can use fork

Comment: If you can use `fork`, and you have good reason to do so, the code is actually simpler. Each spawned thread corresponds to a `fork`; if the return value indicates you're in the child process, you call the desired function then exit the child process with whatever exit code makes sense (possibly using `quick_exit` or `_Exit` to avoid flushing buffers, if you didn't make sure to `fflush(NULL);` before each `fork`). If the return value indicates you're the parent, you store it off (e.g. in an array) and call `waitpid` on it later to verify the child has exited and collect its exit code.

Comment: There are *many* docs on `fork`; the most basic is `man 2 fork` that will tell you all about the system call and what the return values mean.

Answer (score 0):

> How to rewrite this code using processes instead of threads?

ShadowRanger said, "multiprocess designs are less portable, and generally more expensive."

The thing that distinguishes threads is, they all run in the same virtual address space. It is trivially easy to let several threads access the same global variables or the same heap objects. It is significantly more work to create [memory regions that are shared between processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory#In_software) and, to create the means of constructing data structures within those shared regions.

In addition, your program will need to use various [*inter-process communication*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) (IPC) means to synchronize access to the shared memory. Many multi-process applications forego the shared memory altogether and rely entirely on IPC for communication between different processes. But then, re-structuring a program that previously used shared memory to use IPC instead potentially is a *huge* task.

On top of all that, the library calls you'll need to make in order use IPC, and optionally, to create a shared memory region, will be different on different operating systems. So, if you need your program to be portable across platforms, that adds a whole 'nother level of complexity.

---

> `OS_WORK()`, ... `OS_CS_WORK()`

There is no *general* answer to your question. The answer to how *you* can port *your* program is going to depend very much on what those functions do and, on how they communicate with each other.